# asp.net gridview focus not working in microsoft edge browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, microsoft-edge

I have tried with the below code to focus current row after save from the popup in the grid view(asp.net)

```
 GridViewRow row1 = (GridViewRow)ImgPriorityFlag.NamingContainer;
 row1.Focus();
```

Here, ImgPriorityFlag is the image button in the grid.

It is working fine in google chrome, mozilla firefox but not working in microsoft edge. How to fix this issue.

Comment: According to your description, I created a simple demo and it works fine with Button(I tested with button instead of imagebutton) in Edge. What is your current version of Edge? If possible, could you provide sample code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: What is the code executed on the client site ? What JS (and/or Html) is generated from this c# code ?